# add a new column based on other row values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe named "`test`" and a list of words `list_w = ['monthly', 'moon']`. I want to add a new column "`revised cosine`" such that: for each word present in `list_w` with '`weak`' condition with `cosine == 'Na'`, the revised cosine of their corresponding condition '`unrel_weak`' will also be '`Na`', similarly for each word present in list_w with '`strong`' condition with `cosine == 'Na'`, their `revised cosine` of their corresponding condition '`unrel_strong`' will also be '`Na`'

```
     isi       prime   target     condition  meanRT cosine 
0     50      weekly  monthly        strong   676.2    0.9
1   1050      weekly  monthly        strong   643.5    0.9
2     50       daily  monthly          weak   737.2     Na
3   1050       daily  monthly          weak   670.6     Na
4     50     bathtub  monthly  unrel_strong   692.2    0.1
5   1050     bathtub  monthly  unrel_strong   719.1    0.1
6     50      sponge  monthly    unrel_weak   805.8    0.3
7   1050      sponge  monthly    unrel_weak   685.7    0.3
8     50    crescent     moon        strong   625.0     Na
9   1050    crescent     moon        strong   537.2     Na
10    50      sunset     moon          weak   698.4    0.2
11  1050      sunset     moon          weak   704.3    0.2
12    50    premises     moon  unrel_strong   779.2    0.7
13  1050    premises     moon  unrel_strong   647.6    0.7
14    50     descent     moon    unrel_weak   686.0    0.5
15  1050     descent     moon    unrel_weak   725.4    0.5
```

My code is as below:

```
for w in list_w:
    if test.loc[(test['target']==w) & (test['condition']=='strong'), 'cosine']=='Na':
        test.loc[(test['target']==w) & (test['condition']=='unrel_strong'), 'cosine'] ='Na'
```

My code returns error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My expected output should be like in the dataframe below (with "`revised cosine`" column added)

```
     isi       prime   target     condition  meanRT cosine revised cosine
0     50      weekly  monthly        strong   676.2    0.9  0.9
1   1050      weekly  monthly        strong   643.5    0.9  0.9
2     50       daily  monthly          weak   737.2     Na  Na
3   1050       daily  monthly          weak   670.6     Na  Na
4     50     bathtub  monthly  unrel_strong   692.2    0.1  0.1
5   1050     bathtub  monthly  unrel_strong   719.1    0.1  0.1
6     50      sponge  monthly    unrel_weak   805.8    0.3  Na
7   1050      sponge  monthly    unrel_weak   685.7    0.3  Na
8     50    crescent     moon        strong   625.0     Na  Na
9   1050    crescent     moon        strong   537.2     Na  Na
10    50      sunset     moon          weak   698.4    0.2  0.2
11  1050      sunset     moon          weak   704.3    0.2  0.2
12    50    premises     moon  unrel_strong   779.2    0.7  Na
13  1050    premises     moon  unrel_strong   647.6    0.7  Na
14    50     descent     moon    unrel_weak   686.0    0.5  0.5
15  1050     descent     moon    unrel_weak   725.4    0.5  0.5
```

any ideas to help me out? I checked logical_and but they seem to work only with 2 conditions.
Overwritting the `cosine` colum is also fine, as long as the output is like the `revised cosine`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please [don't post images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) instead add them in text format so that we could be able to copy these while trying to answer your question. Please take some time to read [How to ask good pandas questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

This error message comes from the fact that you can't do if statements like this with Pandas.

Try like this:

```py
for w in list_w:
    for c in ["weak", "strong"]:
        mask = (
            (test["target"] == w) & (test["condition"] == c) & (test["cosine"] == "Na")
        )
        test.loc[mask, "revised cosine"] = "Na"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
m = test['cosine'].eq('Na') & \
    test['target'].isin(list_w) & \
    test['condition'].isin(['weak', 'strong'])

i1 = test.set_index(['isi', 'target', 'condition']).index
i2 = test[m].set_index(['isi', 'target', test.loc[m, 'condition'].radd('unrel_')]).index

test['revised_cosine'] = test['cosine'].mask(i1.isin(i2), 'Na')
```

#### Explanations

Let us create a boolean mask `m` which holds `True` when the `cosine` column contains `Na` and at the same time `target` column contains one of the word from `list_w` and `condition` column is either `weak` or `strong`

```
>>> m

0     False
1     False
2      True
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
dtype: bool
```

Create a `MultiIndex` based on the columns `isi`, `target` and `condition`, lets call it `i1`. Filter the rows in `test` dataframe using mask `m`, add a prefix `unrel_` to the filtered rows in `condition` column and create another MultiIndex `i2` in the similar way.

```
>>> i1
MultiIndex([(  50, 'monthly',       'strong'),
            (1050, 'monthly',       'strong'),
            (  50, 'monthly',         'weak'),
            (1050, 'monthly',         'weak'),
            (  50, 'monthly', 'unrel_strong'),
            (1050, 'monthly', 'unrel_strong'),
            (  50, 'monthly',   'unrel_weak'),
            (1050, 'monthly',   'unrel_weak'),
            (  50,    'moon',       'strong'),
            (1050,    'moon',       'strong'),
            (  50,    'moon',         'weak'),
            (1050,    'moon',         'weak'),
            (  50,    'moon', 'unrel_strong'),
            (1050,    'moon', 'unrel_strong'),
            (  50,    'moon',   'unrel_weak'),
            (1050,    'moon',   'unrel_weak')],
           names=['isi', 'target', 'condition'])

>>> i2
MultiIndex([(  50, 'monthly',   'unrel_weak'),
            (1050, 'monthly',   'unrel_weak'),
            (  50,    'moon', 'unrel_strong'),
            (1050,    'moon', 'unrel_strong')],
           names=['isi', 'target', 'condition'])
```

`Mask` the values in `cosine` column using a boolean mask which can be created by testing the membership of `i1` in `i2`

```
     isi     prime   target     condition  meanRT cosine revised_cosine
0     50    weekly  monthly        strong   676.2    0.9            0.9
1   1050    weekly  monthly        strong   643.5    0.9            0.9
2     50     daily  monthly          weak   737.2     Na             Na
3   1050     daily  monthly          weak   670.6     Na             Na
4     50   bathtub  monthly  unrel_strong   692.2    0.1            0.1
5   1050   bathtub  monthly  unrel_strong   719.1    0.1            0.1
6     50    sponge  monthly    unrel_weak   805.8    0.3             Na
7   1050    sponge  monthly    unrel_weak   685.7    0.3             Na
8     50  crescent     moon        strong   625.0     Na             Na
9   1050  crescent     moon        strong   537.2     Na             Na
10    50    sunset     moon          weak   698.4    0.2            0.2
11  1050    sunset     moon          weak   704.3    0.2            0.2
12    50  premises     moon  unrel_strong   779.2    0.7             Na
13  1050  premises     moon  unrel_strong   647.6    0.7             Na
14    50   descent     moon    unrel_weak   686.0    0.5            0.5
15  1050   descent     moon    unrel_weak   725.4    0.5            0.5
```